# Is there any 'Scene Changed Listener' in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, stage

I have an application where I use a plugin manager to load plugins:

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Platform.setImplicitExit(false);    

        try {
            AnchorPane root = (AnchorPane)FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/StartWindow.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root, 420, 215);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
        }

        try {
            final PluginManager pluginManager = new DefaultPluginManager();
            pluginManager.loadPlugins();
            pluginManager.startPlugins();
            List<Module> modules = pluginManager.getExtensions(Module.class);

            for (Module module : modules) {
                module.initModule(primaryStage);
            }
        } catch(Exception ex) {
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

After I load an fxml and show the window, I load up the plugins (Module.class). Each module has an initModule() method what I call to initialize that plugin. I pass the primaryStage to it so I can do changes on the StartWindow, but from the StartWindow's controller I open up multiple windows, other fxmls with other controllers.

My question is, is there any way to write some kind of "SceneChangedListener" so my Module plugin will be notified if a new window opened so I can modify it from my plugin?

Answer (score 2):

There is a [SceneProperty](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Window.html#sceneProperty--) you can monitor to see if the scene attached to a window changes.

There is no public Java 8 API to monitor all of the windows known to the JavaFX runtime.  That information would be available from an unsupported private API that you might find if you wanted to review the [JavaFX source code](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/OpenJFX/Main), though making use of unsupported private APIs is not recommended for most applications.  Probably, internally, [ScenicView](http://fxexperience.com/scenic-view/) works this way and you might get some more information on the process by asking the ScenicView developers.

Answer (score 1):

Just for those who might look at this in the future. Since Java 9 the Window class has a public static observable list

```
public static ObservableList<Window> getWindows()
```

which can be used to track the currently open windows. No need for hacks anymore.

Answer (score 0):

As it seems there is no native method for this, finally I solved this issue with a much easier trick, using EventBus, I send a custom event every time when I fire up a new window. My plugins are subscribed to that event. Also sending the Scene as a parameter with the event so my plugins can modify any window.